# Out of memory error in vbs scripts

Tags: vbscript, wmi, createobject

I've been facing this dialogue box just after I start my script

```
Script: C:\konica.vbs
Line: 14
Char: 1
Error: Out of Memory: 'GetObject'
Code: 800A0007
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

This is my script:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCurrDir = Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "")


'### Konica ###

strIPAddress = "192.168.110.168"
strComputer = "."
strPrinterName = "Konica"
strDriverName = "KONICA MINOLTA C353 Series PS"
strLocation = "Konica"
strInfFile = "\\stp\HHard\Printers\KONICA MINOLTA\XP(x86)\BHC353PSWinx86_6500RU\BHC353PSWinx86_6500RU\KOAZXA__.INF"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(LoadDriver)}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Printer Where PortName = 'IP_" & strIPAddress & "' ")
For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
    MsgBox "Unable to install printer, printer already found on port 'IP_" & strIPAddress & "'." & VbCrlf & VbCrlf & "Found:  " & objPrinter.DeviceID, vbExclamation + vbSystemModal, "Printer Port already assigned"
    WSCript.Quit 114001
Next
'MsgBox(strIPAddress)
Set objNewPort = objWMIService.Get("Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort").SpawnInstance_
objNewPort.Name = "IP_" & strIPAddress
objNewPort.Protocol = 1
objNewPort.HostAddress = strIPAddress
objNewPort.PortNumber = "9100"
objNewPort.SNMPEnabled = False
objNewPort.Put_

wshShell.Run "rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b """ & strPrinterName & """ /f """ & strInfFile & """ /r ""IP_" & strIPAddress & """ /m """ & strDriverName & """", 1, True

Set colPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Printer Where DeviceID = '" & strPrinterName & "' ")
For Each objPrinter in colPrinters
    objPrinter.Location = strLocation
    objPrinter.Put_
Next
```

You can see, that it script for installing in my system printer 'Konica'. In other system, it script works fine. Where mistake? Please help ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably on a wrong tangent here but try giving the MsgBox a variable and then using code that doesn't do anything.
For example:

```
MsgBox "Unable to install printer, printer already found on port 'IP_" & strIPAddress & "'." & VbCrlf & VbCrlf & "Found:  " & objPrinter.DeviceID, vbExclamation + vbSystemModal, "Printer Port already assigned"
```

becomes

```
x = MsgBox "Unable to install printer, printer already found on port 'IP_" & strIPAddress & "'." & VbCrlf & VbCrlf & "Found:  " & objPrinter.DeviceID, vbExclamation + vbSystemModal, "Printer Port already assigned"
```

Then you could write

```
If x Then
Else
End If
```

Which would run and do nothing because x is always x but there's nothing to run inside the If statement.

Comment: hmm, ok, I'll take another look.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that your system is low on memory.  The line numbering is questionable in your post, but I would venture a guess that the size of the printer driver is pretty large.